# Scrapy Retrieve Symblos in json if content in arabic

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for test in response.css('div.news-content'):
            yield {
                'author': test.css('h1::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

and run this command line: 
scrapy runspider quotes.py -o quotes.json

if this title contain Arabic content it retrieve this in json:

```
[
    {
        "author": "\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0631\u0627\u0645\u0649 \u0646\u0627\u062c\u0649"
    }
]
```

how can i get this json in arabic ?

Comment: In Python 3, you can see the actual Arabic letters if you print the encoded string: print("\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0631\u0627\u0645\u0649 \u0646\u0627\u062c\u0649")

Comment: it gaves me the same , i want json export in Arabic from begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the `JSON` as `UTF-8 byte`:

```
import json

x = [ { "author": "\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0631\u0627\u0645\u0649 \u0646\u0627\u062c\u0649" } ]

with open('f.json','wb') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(x,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))
```

Output file:

[image]